# Resulting Solid Questions Help?

Tags: calculus, rotations

Q: A ball of radius 17 has a round hole of radius 8 drilled through its center. Find the volume of the resulting solid.

A: 4500pi

I am mostly confused about the question...If we have a bead-like object, then how are we suppose to rotate it to make a solid? I guess I am just having a hard time visualizing this? In regards to the math part, I suppose I just need to find the volume of revolution for the cylinder and the ball separately then subtract them? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You know the volume of a sphere and a cylinder; your remaining challenge is to figure out the volume of a spherical cap; you have to subtract two volumes of those to get your answer.

Comment: How do I do that? Subtract the volume of a similar square/2 or something?

Comment: [Just to give you an idea...](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set this volume up as a single integral, begin by drawing the circle of radius 17, centered at the origin in the xy-plane.  Draw the line y=8.  Let $R$ be the region in your circle and above the line $y=8$.  Then the volume you seek is the volume of the solid of revolution created by revolving $R$ about the $x$-axis.  The [disk (or cross section) method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) works well for finding this volume.  Any (modern) calculus text will cover this topic, with lots of examples.

Note you will want to find the intersection of the line $y=8$ and your circle in order to determine your limits of integration.